# How could i post an image in Facebook feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I've been using Facebook's Feed Dialog to let users on a site share content on their Facebook feed. On their feed there would be a picture that serves as a link to the page on my site, with some text below it like name, caption and description fields. All of these - picture, name, caption and description are now deprecated and stop working now :( Is there any other way to achieve this functionality using a different method, i've proved the quote parameter but I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post pictures on user profiles, not with the API and not with the feed dialog. The feed dialog is for sharing URLs, but they can include an image in the `og:image` tag of the page source. So you just need to add the correct image in the page source, with an absolut path: https://ogp.me/